# percentage of numbers starting with $2$ in $\{2^n\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, reference-request, fourier-analysis

I have once heard a professor telling (during a course on Fourier theory) that there is a way to determine the numbers starting with a $2$ in the sequence $\{2^n\colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. I asked him about it, but he could not remember how. The proof involved the theory of [equidistributed sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_mod_1) the [Weyl criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_criterion).

Is there someone who knows how to prove this? Or is there a nice reference (preferably a book)?

Comment: As a start, note that $2^{10}=1024$, so until $n$ is very large, the numbers $\{2, 256\}$ will represent the "two out of every ten" which begin with the digit $2$.

Comment: You question could be interpreted to mean "For what value of $n$ does $2^n$ start with a 2?" which is somewhat different from the answer presented by mercio.

Answer (score 4):

$2^n$ begins with a $2$
$\iff 2^n /10^k \in [2;3)$ with $k \in \Bbb N$
$\iff n\log 2- k \log 10 \in [log 2; \log 3)$ with $k \in \Bbb N$
$\iff \left\{n\frac{\log 2}{\log 10}\right\} \in \left[\frac{\log 2}{\log 10}; \frac{\log 3}{\log 10}\right)$, where $\{x\} \in [0;1)$ is the fractional part of $x$.

Since $\frac{\log 2}{\log 10}$ is irrational, the sequence $\left\{n\frac{\log 2}{\log 10}\right\}$ is equidistributed in $[0;1)$, and so it lands in $\left[\frac{\log 2}{\log 10}; \frac{\log 3}{\log 10}\right)$ with "probability" $\frac{\log 3 - \log 2}{\log 10}$.

Comment: @Simen: You’re right; I was getting ahead of myself.